# Is there a way to flip a component while preserving wire locations (in Altium)?

Tags: pcb, altium, schematic

I have placed a header component. I started wiring it, but now I realized that the component should by flipped in the y-direction. If I started at the beginning, it could use the shortcut 'y' to flip/mirror it in the y-direction. But because I have already wired the component, the wires will cross.

Is there a standard way in Altium to flip a component, while keeping the connections at the place? I could of course redraw the connections, but I'm curious if there is a standard way.

Comment: Redraw a new footprint with the pins and numbers reversed then swap the part out. Just redraw it is my advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to rewire the component from the schematic if you want to uncross the wires. If you want to rotate the part then use 'space'. You can also use 'X', but that probably won't do what you want either.

Answer (score 1):

Another option you may consider is control+drag the component away from the nets you have it connected to. Pressing control will cause it to not drag the nets with it. Once you have the component by itself, press Y to flip it on the Y-axis. Then drag it back to the original location. This assumes symmetry in the component so that once flipped it will still align with its connections.